# Multiple Image Fade In/Out

Tags: jquery

I have about 20 different images that I want to fade in and out in 4 boxes. I need it to randomally select an image from the list of images and display it.

Box example photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4 are their names. They need to be individually named as they absolute positioned.

```
<div id="photo1">
    <img src="images/photo.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="images/photo2.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="images/photo3.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="images/photo4.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
    <img src="images/photo5.jpg" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

jquery so far

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//generate random number
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*$("#photo1").children().length);
$(function() {
    //hide all the images (if not already done)
    $("#photo1 > img").hide();

    //set timeout for image to appear (set at 500ms)
    setTimeout(function(){
       //fade in the random index of the image collection
       $("#photo1 > img:eq(" + randomnumber + ")").fadeIn();
    }, 500);       
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code:

```
$(function() {
    // match all divs with ID starting with 'photo'
    $("div[id^=photo] > img").hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
       $("div[id^=photo]").each(function() {
           var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(this).children().length);
           $(this).find('img:eq(' + rand + ')').fadeIn();
       });
    }, 500);       
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Very handy.